# How to get feedback on user input events which allows highlighting the input area of a window and describing the event

Tags: winapi, pywin32, win32gui

Please forgive me if this is a duplicate, but I am having a hard time finding the how to best even search for this question. Also please forgive the long wall of text. There is a tldr at the bottom. I am starting on what will most likely be a python application, but my question is not python specific. I have been tasked with building what is basically going to be an open source alternative to Microsoft's PSR tool.

For those who are not familiar with PSR, the acronym stands for Problem Steps Recorder and it is a small application built into every version of windows since Vista. When you start it, it runs in the background and can take a series of screenshots and builds out an XML file.

The screenshots are taken each time that there is user input into an application. For example, a mouse click of pressing enter to submit something will trigger the screenshot. The optional XML it builds out contains a textual description of the action that triggered the screenshot and the screenshot filename.

The screenshots are a little special in two ways. One, they contain the mouse cursor in the image. Which I have found is hidden in a conventional screenshot by pressing the print-screen key. More importantly, the screenshots are augmented with an outline of the area of the window where the input happened. For example, if you click the back button in explorer, the screenshot will have the back button enclosed into a green rectangle. If you type into a textbox, that screenshot will have the textbox enclosed in the green rectangle.

The xml descriptions say things along the line of "user left clicked on button [back] in window [My Documents] from process explorer.exe"

My assumption is that there is some well documented windows API that would allow me to get this information. I know it's not an undocumented API because Sysinternals Process Explorer can highlight window components in the same way PSR does. If you run Process Explorer and drag the little target around on top of an explorer window, you will see what I am talking about. I know Sysinternals is now part of Microsoft, but it had that feature before the acquisition so it's not some insider knowledge that gave their app that ability.

Unfortunately, Process Explorer is not open source, and I have not been able to find an open source application with the same functionality. My guess of how this would be tackled is to watch for specific types of user input, such as mouse click and various non-character keys like tab, enter, f5, etc. On mouse click get the cursor position, get the in-focus window, find the window position and size, find the positions of the various window components, calculate which component would have been under the cursor at time of click, and use the knowledge of the window component positioning and size, and window positioning and size, and screen resolution to draw a rectangle overlay onto the screenshot.

But I don't know what API calls would give me that info, and that idea doesn't hold up for something like the enter key being pressed to trigger a submit. So maybe there is an API that allows attaching callbacks to all the components of a window, and the callbacks just signal to the app when there is input into that component?

Then there is this XML description. How does it know "user left clicked on button [back] in window [My Documents] from process explorer.exe"? That makes me lean more toward this being some kind of a callback, and that this is just information that gets passed along with it.

I really don't know, and I don't know where to look. So I am reaching out to you here. Does anyone know what APIs I am looking for? It would be so helpful to me if someone has experience with this specific feature, but even if someone can just point me toward an open source app that makes use of this, that would be great to, and I could just figure it out by looking there.

tldr; I need to know what windows api allow Sysinternals Process Explorer and Windows PSR to highlight the components of the window that the mouse is hovering over.

Thank you all in advanced for your help.

Comment: You are propably looking for [UI automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32). It allows you to enumerate UI components and to listen for various events, including user input.

Comment: Or [`SetWinEventHook()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwineventhook), which can also notify you of things like clicks and focus changes.

Comment: Thank you so much zett42 and Remy! I think both of what you pointed out are indispensable to making this happen. They both fall under the category of "Windows Accessibility Features". That make perfect sense. This would be features that are needed by screen readers. I hadn't even thought of that. Thank you for your help.